# Blender in Ipad Pro

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to use Blender with an ipad pro?
I am planning to buy an ipad and it would be decisive to make the decision.
It would be very interesting to be able to use greasse pencil in the ipad pro.

Thanks!

Comment: Ipad pro is running iOS not OS X, Blender is supported on Mac OS (OS X) only. But it  is open source so you could build yourself for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remote desktop, or a cloud service, like this:
https://www.rollapp.com/app/blender

Answer (score 0):

Use duet, available on the apple App Store and from their website. That way you can run blender from the laptop, with the iPad as a second screen. The laptop will do the rendering, and the iPad will be the interface that you control blender from. It’s not free, but a very reasonable one time charge.

Answer (score -2):

The main problem is that an Ipad might not have the CPU power to render that, which is why rollapp is useful, since it does cloud computing.  However, it is also important to note that Blender on rollapp is not free, and I haven't found any other cloud versions that are.

Comment: Most ipads have more than enough computing power for blender, some even outperforming their laptop counterparts.